# How do I generically access this Groovy JSON object?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm using Grails 1.3.6.  I read the following JSON into a variable ...

```
{
    "abc": { 
        "attr1": "value1",
        "attr2": "value2"
    },
    "def": { 
        "attr1": "value1",
        "attr2": "value2"
    },
    "ghi": { 
        "attr1": "value1",
        "attr2": "value2"
    },
    ...
}
```

If, in my controller, I'm passed a parameter referring to one part of the JSON object ...

```
def section = params.section;   // could be "abc", "def", 'ghi", ...e
```

How do I access that part of the JSON assuming the above gets stored into a Groovy variable named "myJSONObject"?  Thanks, - Dave

Comment: How do you getting/storing it?

Comment: Is `myJSONObject` an actual object, or is it just a JSON string (i.e. unparsed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used [`JSON.parse()`](http://grails.org/Converters%20Reference) to create your `myJSONObject`, you can just do:

```
def value = myJsonObject[section]
```